# passing int to .xml for android app

Tags: java, android, xml, string

I have tried searching but I couldn't find the answer to my problem. I'm trying to simply display the value of an int. I want pass it as an int. Here is my code. For some reason instead of diplaying the actual number, its displaying %d.

java code:

```
package ebike.picture.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class PictureActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String hello = getString(R.string.aaa, 10);
    }
}
```

xml code from strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="hello">Hello World, PictureActivity!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Picture</string>
    <string name="aaa">hello %d </string>

</resources>
```

xml code from main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/aaa" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Format string syntax using Java's `Formatter` class is actually different from the syntax you're using, try changing the "aaa" string to the following:

```
<string name="aaa">hello %1$ </string>
```

To understand what's going on you can read more about the syntax here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax